# Ofstream not creating a new file correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, creation, ofstream

I've tried to write a simple database program. The problem is that ofstream does NOT want to make a new file.

Here's an extract from the offending code.

```
void newd()
{
string name, extension, location, fname;
cout << "Input the filename for the new database (no extension, and no backslashes)." << endl << "> ";
getline(cin, name);
cout << endl << "The extension (no dot). If no extension is added, the default is .cla ." << endl << "> ";
getline(cin, extension);
cout << endl << "The full directory (double backslashes). Enter q to quit." << endl << "Also, just fyi, this will overwrite any files that are already there." << endl << "> ";
getline(cin, location);
cout << endl;
if (extension == "")
{
    extension = "cla";
}
if (location == "q")
{
}
else
{
    fname = location + name + "." + extension;
    cout << fname << endl;
    ofstream writeDB(fname);
    int n = 1; //setting a throwaway inteher
    string tmpField, tmpEntry; //temp variable for newest field, entry
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Input the name of the " << n << "th field. If you don't want any more, press enter." << endl;
        getline(cin, tmpField);
        if (tmpField == "")
        {
            break; 
        }
        n++;
        writeDB << tmpField << ": |";
        int j = 1; //another one
        for (;;)
        {
            cout << "Enter the name of the " << j++ << "th entry for " << tmpField << "." << endl << "If you don't want any more, press enter." << endl;
            getline(cin, tmpEntry);
            if (tmpEntry == "")
            {
                break;
            }
            writeDB << " " << tmpEntry << " |";
        }
        writeDB << "¬";
    }
    cout << "Finished writing database. If you want to edit it, open it." << endl;
}
}
```

EDIT: OK, just tried

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream writeDB ("C:\\test.cla");
writeDB << "test";
writeDB.close();
return 0;
}
```

and that didn't work, so it is access permission problems.

Comment: give an example of a program execution and what you're inputting.

Comment: also you don't need "double backslashes" when inputting the string this way, only for string literals in your code.

Comment: Reduce your source to *only* show the problem. Then verify that this indeed *is* the problem. I would guess, you try to open a file in a funny location which doesn't exist. A simple program to verify that `std::ofstream` works as expected would be this: `#include <fstream> int main() { std::ofstream out("empty.txt"); }`. Going from there verify where the created file ceases to be created.

Comment: I don't see any error checking in this code. A simple `if (!writeDB) { /* print some message */ }` would tell you if the stream creation failed.

Comment: @Blastfurnace the problem with that is when I tried that every single path failed, even ones that I knew were completely and entirely valid.

Comment: I think you should un-vandalize this question, and just add a comment about your elevated priv problem, and (when you can) open a new question altogether about elevated privs.

Comment: I don't need this now, so I won't add another question, but thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ofstream writeDB(fname); //-> replace fname with fname.c_str()
```

If you lookup the documentation of the ofstream constructor, you will see something like:
explicit ofstream ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );

The second argument is optional, but the first one is a const char*, and not a string. To solve this problem the most simple way is to convert your string to something called a C-string (char*, which is basically an array of chars); to do that just use c_str() (it«s part of the  library).

Other than that, you could just place the information directly on a C-str, and then pass it normally to the ofstream constructor.

Comment: C++11 adds a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) that takes an `std::string` argument, but if the OP is using an older compiler that code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Thanks for that, I added it, but it still isn't working. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 BTW. Thanks all!